# Generate order confirmation PDF

Tags: magento2, email, pdf, order-confirmation

I am creating a module, that should send invoices and the order(confirmation) pdfs to some declared E-Mail addresses. I am able to do so for the invoices. But I dont know how to generate the order-confirmation pdf files.

For the invoice pdfs I am using:

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice;
```

and I can call it in my class with
`$pdfContent = $this->pdfInvoiceModel->getPdf([$invoice])->render();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out: there is no functionality in magento2 (vanilla) to generate an "Order PDF" - so, you could either generate an own pdf file with the ZEND Framework or use an extension to do so. I am using an extension by XTENTO now.